# How to not select user_ids that have not performed certain actions (Snowflake SQL)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So, I have dataset that looks like below. I would like to write a query that extract users who have done steps 1,2 & 3 but not 4 & 5. The output of the query should be User 1 and User 4.

| User_ID | Steps |
| --- | --- |
| User 1 | Step 1 |
| User 1 | Step 2 |
| User 1 | Step 3 |
| User 2 | Step 1 |
| User 2 | Step 2 |
| User 2 | Step 3 |
| User 2 | Step 4 |
| User 2 | Step 5 |
| User 3 | Step 1 |
| User 3 | Step 2 |
| User 3 | Step 3 |
| User 3 | Step 4 |
| User 3 | Step 5 |
| User 4 | Step 1 |
| User 4 | Step 2 |
| User 4 | Step 3 |

Trying to use NOT IN but it does not work.

Tried using NOT IN but it does not work. I'm a bit new to SQL so help would be appreciated.
The result of the SQL query should be distinct user_ids that did not perform step 4 & 5.
Expected result:
User 1
User 4

Comment: Can there be steps 6 and 7, or is 5 the max per user? If 5 is max, then look into `group by` and `having`.

Comment: @Isolated
There are limited no. of steps only.
You mean 
group by user_id 
having step >= 4 ??

Comment: Can you simply return those users with fewer than 5 distinct steps? This would accomplish it: `select user_id from my_data group by user_id having count(distinct steps) < 5`

Comment: I get your logic, but in the actual dataset, the step values are varchar so cannot simply use <5. Thank though

Comment: How many steps are per user are possible? Is there a maximum number?

Comment: You can `count` anything. Varchar vs Integer has nothing to do with it. Try it and you'll see it works. If you have just 5 steps, then this is the easiest solution.

Comment: There are 5 steps but in reality it looks like
1. Login_page
2. Enter_email
3. Enter_pwd
4. Click_login
5. View_accounts

with the numeric value preceding the step

Comment: Please edit the question to show your real use case. Answers might not cover your use case if the data in the question doesn't show your use case. You should also be more precise about the exact logic you want to build.

Comment: The problem with using count(distinct steps) <5 is that the data isn't all clean so, sometime, the sequence of events is not captured correctly or are missing. 
Answer provided by Tim below gets me what I wanted but I appreciate all of your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your requirement is to find users who have only done steps 1, 2, and 3.  One approach uses aggregation:

```sql
SELECT User_ID
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY User_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Steps) = 3 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Steps NOT IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

The first `COUNT` in the `HAVING` clause ensures that there are exactly 3 distinct steps for a matching user.  The second `COUNT` ensures that those steps can only be 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: Thank you this worked. 
Is there a simpler way/another way of doing this? It is a bit complicated for me at this time.

Answer (score 0):

The complex answer is to use a [MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/match_recognize) or you can hand roll one

### Assumption:

*If we assume have many instances of a rule does not count against the rule, then we can*

### Code:

Firstly assign a bit per step, then aggregate OR them. Then check for bits 1-3 but not 4-5

So a CTE with the data:

```
with data(user_id, steps) as (
    select * from values
       ('User 1', 'Step 1'),
       ('User 1', 'Step 2'),
       ('User 1', 'Step 3'),
       ('User 2', 'Step 1'),
       ('User 2', 'Step 2'),
       ('User 2', 'Step 3'),
       ('User 2', 'Step 4'),
       ('User 2', 'Step 5'),
       ('User 3', 'Step 1'),
       ('User 3', 'Step 2'),
       ('User 3', 'Step 3'),
       ('User 3', 'Step 4'),
       ('User 3', 'Step 5'),
       ('User 4', 'Step 1'),
       ('User 4', 'Step 2'),
       ('User 4', 'Step 3')
)
```

then we can do what special logic is needed to test is this row rule 1 - 5:

```
select 
    user_id,
    case
        when steps = 'Step 1' then 1 /* 2^0 */   
        when steps = 'Step 2' then 2 /* 2^1 */
        when steps = 'Step 3' then 4 /* 2^2 */
        when steps = 'Step 4' then 8 /* 2^3 */
        when steps = 'Step 5' then 16 /* 2^4 */
    end as flag_bits
from data
```

[image: flag logic results]

now we aggregate those bits:

```
 WITH flag_logic as (
    select 
        user_id,
        case
            when steps = 'Step 1' then 1 /* 2^0 */   
            when steps = 'Step 2' then 2 /* 2^1 */
            when steps = 'Step 3' then 4 /* 2^2 */
            when steps = 'Step 4' then 8 /* 2^3 */
            when steps = 'Step 5' then 16 /* 2^4 */
        end as flag_bits
    from data
)
select 
    user_id,
    BITOR_AGG(flag_bits) as flags,
    concat('0x', TO_CHAR(flags, 'XX')) as hex_flags
from flag_logic
group by 1
```

gives:

| USER_ID | FLAGS | HEX_FLAGS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | 7 | 0x7 |
| User 2 | 31 | 0x1F |
| User 3 | 31 | 0x1F |
| User 4 | 7 | 0x7 |

so we can see the User 1 & User 4 have the three first rules, and not any of the Rules 4 or 5 which could be written

```
select 
    user_id,
    BITOR_AGG(flag_bits) as flags,
    concat('0x', trim(TO_CHAR(flags, 'XX'))) as hex_flags,
    BITAND(flags, (1+2+4)) = (1+2+4) as has_rules_1_2_3,
    BITAND(flags, (8+16)) = 0 as has_no_rule_4_or_5,
    has_rules_1_2_3 AND has_no_rule_4_or_5 as what_to_keep
from flag_logic
group by 1
```

gives:

[image]

so now we can move these parts around:

```
with data(user_id, steps) as (
    select * from values
       ('User 1', 'Step 1'),
       ('User 1', 'Step 2'),
       ('User 1', 'Step 3'),
       ('User 2', 'Step 1'),
       ('User 2', 'Step 2'),
       ('User 2', 'Step 3'),
       ('User 2', 'Step 4'),
       ('User 2', 'Step 5'),
       ('User 3', 'Step 1'),
       ('User 3', 'Step 2'),
       ('User 3', 'Step 3'),
       ('User 3', 'Step 4'),
       ('User 3', 'Step 5'),
       ('User 4', 'Step 1'),
       ('User 4', 'Step 2'),
       ('User 4', 'Step 3')
), flag_logic as (
    select 
        user_id,
        case
            when steps = 'Step 1' then 1 /* 2^0 */   
            when steps = 'Step 2' then 2 /* 2^1 */
            when steps = 'Step 3' then 4 /* 2^2 */
            when steps = 'Step 4' then 8 /* 2^3 */
            when steps = 'Step 5' then 16 /* 2^4 */
        end as flag_bits
    from data
)
select 
    user_id
from flag_logic
group by 1
having BITAND(BITOR_AGG(flag_bits), (1+2+4)) = (1+2+4) 
    and BITAND(BITOR_AGG(flag_bits), (8+16)) = 0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This won't be as performant as Tim's solution, but you might find it easier to read

```
select user_id
from yourtable
where steps in (1,2,3)
group by user_id
having count(distinct steps) = 3

except

select user_id
from yourtable
where steps in (4,5)
```